# How to make your hotel room dark?

Tags: travel, light

Curtains in hotel rooms are often not thick enough to block light from outside. They also don't cover the edges of the window well. Last year in Norway, it was difficult to sleep with the sun shining into the room at 2 am in the morning.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than making your hotel room dark, you could use an sleep shade (photo from Amazon, but there are many types available). Also called a sleep mask.

[image]

It's worn over the eyes, in case that isn't obvious. Another photo from [here](https://wanelo.com/shop/sleep-mask):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With limited ressources in a Hotel I can only think of a couple things.

- Spare blankets
- Used towels
- other fabrics

If you don't have a curtain rail to hang it over you can try to put it in the window.
Open the window slightly and tuck the fabric into the top egde of the window.
Don't squeeze to much fabric in there - windows are already leaking your warm air out.

Answer (score 2):

For what I am suggesting, you need:

- Spare blankets or cloth
- Painter's tape or duct tape

Tape spare blankets or cloth to the window to block the sun. Be sure that your material is thick enough to block the Sun. Also be sure that your tape is strong enough to support the weight.

Answer (score 2):

I know its neurotic, but I always travel with my own black out material (available at fabric stores), and plenty of clothes pins. I pin the fabric to the existing curtain.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the front desk to move you to a different room. Specify one that isn't facing the sun or has longer curtains.

Answer (score 0):

I take my own block out curtains and a set of large bull dog clips

Comment: This is very similar to an existing answer, that suggests blackout curtains and safety pins.  Can you explain how bulldog clips are better?